# Flutter TextFormField hide when keyboard appears

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, singlechildscrollview

I'm new on flutter and i have a problem.
When i click on the textformField, this one disappears

I put in red the container but normaly it's transparent

I put a stack, then in the background the GoogleMap which is extend. And to have a research effect I put an overlay with the textformfield and I will have specific filter buttons instead of the yellow and green.

The problem is that when I click on the textformfield, it disappears from the screen.
I tried to play with the SingleChildScrollView, ListView, but I still have errors especially because of GoogleMap which takes up all the space
Everything is contained by a Scaffold

Can you help me please, where to give me a solution?
I enclose the code below

cordially

[image]

[image]

return Stack(
children: [
/// GoogleMap
Column(
children: [
Expanded(
child: GoogleMap(initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition),
),
],
),

```
    /// Search Bar And Filter
    Positioned.fill(
      bottom: _searchBarContainer,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                /// Search Bar
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: DesignWidget.inputDecorationTexFieldMap(
                        _searchBarMap, Icons.search),
                  ),
                ),

                /// Filter
                Container(
                  width: _filterContainer,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.yellow,
                        width: _filterContainer / 2,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        width: _filterContainer / 2,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply user this pakage [material_floating_search_bar: ^0.3.4]

Answer (score 0):

I think before you use textFormField you either have to define a key or controller.....it happens when you don't define an instance of controller and use that controller inside of textFormField controller.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the solution
I need to add (to Scallfold) : resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false